# Using VectorDrawable from resources in code

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-drawable, android-appcompat, android-vectordrawable

Wanted to ask. What is the right way to use VectorDrawable from resources? 
with support library  `compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.1'`

Because getDrawable() is deprecated and when I use `ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_cancel_button);` for setting toolbar navigation image like this

```
if(toolbar != null)
{
toolbar.setNavigationIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this, R.drawable.ic_cancel_button));
}
```

The error occures.

```
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/ic_cancel_button.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f02005e
```

Comment: You can use this : ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.your_drawable, null)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [`AppCompatResources.getDrawable(Context context, @DrawableRes int resId)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/content/res/AppCompatResources.html#getDrawable(android.content.Context,%20int)).

Comment: And there is no other way except this?

Comment: None that I'm aware of.

Comment: @Twinkle_Monkey, I wonder why won't it fulfill your needs?

Comment: it actualy works, but with little edit, like this: `AppCompatDrawableManager.get().getDrawable(@NonNull Context context, @DrawableRes int resId)`

Comment: @azizbekian, It will, I was just wondering)

Comment: Using not public api is not a good idea...

Comment: @Selvin, it's the suggested way that is currently available through the framework. Your comment should also imply suggesting a better solution.

Comment: Suggested by who?  Why my comment should imply something?  I'm only comment this solution and as any other non public api usage is bad.

Comment: Not who, suggested by the framework. Do you know other solution to this? I do not claim, that using non public API is a nice thing do to.

Comment: `AppCompatDrawableManager.get().getDrawable(@NonNull Context context, @DrawableRes int resId)` Of course it isn't a suggested way... The  question is a duplicate... And an answer is there...